# Angular 1 - $anchorScroll without changing URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I have this elements in my html :

```
  <button class="btn"
          type="button"
          ng-click="$ctrl.scrollTo()">
  </button>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

my method `scrollTo()` :

```
scrollTo() {
  this.$location.hash('result')
}
```

This works well, but I would like a solution that does not change the URL (do not add #result in the URL), and also if possible add a smooth scrolling.

You have solutions close to the solution I made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$anchorScroll as it's name says scrolls to `anchor` or `id` on page, as far as I know it will always change URL. But there are tons of different solutions for this problem.

One example - you can use native scrollIntoView (check compatibility, but it works in all decent browsers, even IE8):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

So you would do something like this to get smooth scroll effect:

```
 // play around with options if you want - you can put block: "start" which doesn't play very nice with jsfiddle but should work fine on any machine. 
    $window.document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end"});
```

I've prepared quick example for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/eoa8v03y/4/